# How to avoid lint error when overriding fields in dart

Tags: flutter, dart, tdd

**Issue resolved!!!**

```
class LoginEntity extends Equatable {
      final String? email;
      final String? accessToken;

  const LoginEntity({required this.email, required this.accessToken});

  @override
  List<Object?> get props => [email];
}

class LoginModel extends LoginEntity {
  final String? accessToken;
  final String? email;

  const LoginModel({this.email, this.accessToken})
      : super(email: email, accessToken: accessToken);
}
```

[lint error dart Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eDcJ1.png)

Please look into the image link attached.

Actually, lint error is populating indicating to not override the fields as to follow best practices.

How to achieve this without reusing the code as I don't want to override fields and find an optimal solution?

Flutter 2.10.0
Dart version: 2.16.0

Comment: The error message includes links with more detailed information.  You need to add `@override` to your overridden members.

Answer (score 0):

I think you don't need to add a field in the inherited class.

You can try like this.

```
class LoginModel extends LoginEntity {
  const LoginModel({String? email, String? accessToken})
      : super(email: email, accessToken: accessToken);
}
```